# PrimeFaces css is not loaded properly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I added the PrimeFaces dependency in my maves project and everything works fine except the css. For example, I am trying to reproduce this panel ( https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/ribbon.xhtml ) in my project, everything works fine but the css style is not displayed well.

Here is my result:
[image: result]
Here is my code:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
      <p:ribbon>

 <!-- Here is the code from the link from above  -->

</p:ribbon>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS looks fine, most likely a icon/fontawesome issue... Inspect with a browser developer tool

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the colors and the borders' styles are not loaded correctly. But I don't know why..

Comment: Inspect with a browser developer tool...

Comment: I see borders, in color...

Comment: What if you add a `p:inputText` to the page?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if you don't have that png or any kind of desired icon inside your project. Please inspect your code in google dev tools and send us a screenshot for this specific link http://prntscr.com/orn8yq.

Comment: Like stated already in the comments...  (besides the screenshot of the browser developer tool since OP should inspect the contents and not verbatim just post it) ;-)